# Subquery and linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**This Query Works**

```
select c.claimid, c.member, c.authno, c.claim_type, c.provider, c.vendor, 
    c.claimdeny, c.date_approved, c.date_received, c.lob 
from xxx.xxx.dbo.clm c 
where c.claimid in (
    select **top 12** d.DENIAL_CLAIM_ID 
    from DN_APPEAL_REQUEST d 
    where d.DENIAL_TYPE='C' order by APPEAL_ID
)
```

**This Query does not Work**

```
select c.claimid, c.member, c.authno, c.claim_type, c.provider, c.vendor, 
    c.claimdeny, c.date_approved, c.date_received, c.lob 
from xxx.xxx.dbo.clm c 
where c.claimid in (
    select **top 13** d.DENIAL_CLAIM_ID 
    from DN_APPEAL_REQUEST d 
    where d.DENIAL_TYPE='C' order by APPEAL_ID
)
```

xxx.xxx is a linked server

the second query runs for a while and then fails with a error message stating that the previous sql statement format was wrong.

---

**Results from first sub query**

```
913900133      
916303197      
833701140      
028100832      
028100832      
028100832      
835900898      
205407041      
214402039      
112504239      
213601714      
314700730
```

**Results from second subquery**

```
913900133      
916303197      
833701140      
028100832      
028100832      
028100832      
835900898      
205407041      
214402039      
112504239      
213601714      
314700730      
214301493
```

The dn_appeal_request has only 18 records. I tried to run query on the linked server table for each and every claimid separately. it works without issues.

Comment: Are `c.claimid` and `d.DENIAL_CLAIM_ID` by chance different datatypes?  I suspect one is possibly a numeric field and the other is a char/varchar field, and you're getting a casting error.

Comment: Can you tell us the data types? Can you also show us the 13 values that come back from the second subquery?

Comment: The datatype is varchar(50) in the linked server and varchar(20) in dn_appeal_request

Comment: @aaron. i have posted the results from both sub-queries

Comment: Well, those aren't the same data types!

Comment: @aaron i made both columns varchar(50) still no luck.

Comment: @VivekChandraprakash Can you post the exact error message that you're getting?

Comment: OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "ServerName" returned message "The connection is no longer usable because the server response for a previously executed statement was incorrectly formatted.".

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/136ebc28-cce5-4c88-a534-973ad04c8b65) of use.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.